# How can I manage Empathy (Online) accounts in Lubuntu 12.10?

Tags: lubuntu, empathy, 12.10

I use empathy, but in Lubuntu Quantal, I cannot add/manage accounts...

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Where did you download lubuntu from?

Comment: I've download it from: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Online accounts can be accessed by command line (package gnome-online-accounts must be installed):

```
gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

Comment: I added my google account via the dialog for that command, but Empathy still says I need to setup an account... Any ideas?

Comment: In short there are separate Gnome and Ubuntu versions of online accounts (more info here - http://debarshiray.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/goa-why-it-is-the-way-it-is/). Empathy on Ubuntu is patched to use the Ubuntu version which is why you're seeing no effect. That version can be accessed by running `gnome-control-center credentials`.

Answer (score 2):

The .desktop file for `gnome-credentials-panel` may not be enabled for LXDE. You will need to edit the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-credentials-panel.desktop` and add `LXDE` to the `OnlyShowIn` section.

Then run `gnome-control-center credentials` from a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In Quantal the command line should be `gnome-control-center credentials` instead of `gnome-control-center online-accounts`. I don't know whether there's any difference in Lubuntu.

Comment: The account settings dialog in Empathy executes `gnome-control-center credentials`, but Lubuntu 12.10's System Settings window is all messed up- it only has 3 items, Language Support, Printers, and Software Sources. Also, the Personal, Hardware, and System group heading icons appear to not be found. So I guess the `gnome-control-center credentials` option in the System Settings isn't there? How are we supposed to use Empathy then?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the info, it works for me (I have ubuntu, and then installed `lubuntu-desktop`).

1. NORMAL INSTALLATION OF UBUNTU
2. `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`
3. Login with the lubuntu desktop
4. `sudo apt install gnome-control-center online-accounts`

*Original answer in Spanish:*

Muchas gracias por la información, me funcionó (tengo ubuntu, y luego instalé el escritorio de lubuntu).

1. INSTALACIÓN NORMAL DE UBUNTU
2. `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`
3. Abrir sesión con el escritorio de lubuntu
4. `sudo apt install gnome-control-center online-accounts`

Comment: Bienvenido. Tenga en cuenta que este es un sitio web en inglés y que su pregunta debe publicarse en inglés. ¿Podrías modificarlo?